# How to effectively use the "Array" schema type to edit a single element and re-save the array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Like what the title said, I'm looking to find the best way to store an array in mongodb (using mongoose) and retrieve the array at anytime and manipulate it?

I tried storing the array as a string in mongoDB and converting it back to an array when I needed to edit it, but I feel that this way is impractical.

So my question is how can I store the array in mongoDB using the "array" Schema Type and what is the best and most effective way to retrive and edit and restore my array?

For example

```
eg = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I want to edit the array to this:

```
eg = [0, 1, 6, 3]
```

Is there a way i could easily access the array?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure exactly what are you trying to accomplish, I will assume that you wish to replace the 3rd value (index=2) in the array (value 2) with the new value 6.

Let's say that schema looks like:

```
let arrayTestSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        values: [Number]
    }
)
```

Insert can be done with:

```
arrayTest.create({name:"test1", values:[0,1,2,3]})
```

And the replacement with:

```
arrayTest.updateOne({name:"test1"}, {$set: {"values.2":6}})
```

Please note that 2 in `values.2` represents the index in the array `values`.